# Google Play Services high mobile data consumption

Tags: android, google-play-services

We are using Android tablets ( Android 10 or above) with SIM. There is an issue with Google play services, since its consuming a lot of mobile data. Is there any possibility to restrict Google play services using Mobile data ?

I know that we can disable background mobile data usage from the Settings, but we have more than 100 devices and we are searching for a solution which avoids manual work.

Extra info: We are also using MDM to distribute our private app and some configurations, but MDM that we are using doesnt have such feature. So we are searching for any other solution to fix this issue.

Possible solutions:

1. As I explained above manual solution will not work in our case. So, going to Settings and disabling apps from using mobile data is not a solution for us.
2. Turning off mobile data when its not in use is not a solution, either. Since some tablets will work only with SIM.
3. Firewall app - again its a manual work.

Comment: What is "a lot of mobile data" for you? 100MB or 1GB or more?

Comment: Around 15-20 mb per day is used only by Google play services.

Comment: That is indeed a lot. BTW: Your question is a bit off-topic here as it is unrelated to programming. Unfortunately I can not migrate questions to https://android.stackexchange.com, so I recommend to re-post your question there and delete this.